# Поведение цикла while

Tags: while

**Немогу понять,как себя ведёт такой цикл?**

```
while(i++<5) alert(i);
```

**Чем же отличается**

```
while(++i<5) alert(i);
```

от

```
while(i++<5) alert(i);
```

Comment: чем же отличается 

    while(++i<5) alert(i);

от 

    while(i++<5) alert(i);

Comment: То что вам так непонятно - это азы программирования. Боюсь, вам надо начинать с изучения этих самых  азов, как это ни печально.

Comment: Я это и делаю.Ответьте,раз эти азы вам понятны.

Comment: позвольте тогда сначала узнать, с помощью чего вы эти азы изучаете? Так как если уж в вашем учебнике не говорится о том, чем отличается ++i от i++, то вам явно стоит сменить учебник.

Comment: Послушайте,счас изучаю Javascript,до этого приходилось кодить на языке,у которого нет инкрементов и декрементов.

Comment: var i=0;
i++;//0
++i;//2
++i;//3
i++;//3
i;//4
Вся я с этими инкрементами понимаю,но как ведёт себя цикл в данной ситуации пытался понять,но чтобы не ошибиться,у вас хотел спросить:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.

```
var i=0;
while(i++<5) {
    alert(i);
}
```

Ход выполнения:

```
//i++=0; i=1;
//i++=1; i=2;
//i++=2; i=3;
//i++=3; i=4;
//i++=4; i=5;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Сравнивает i < 5
2. Увеличивает i на 1
3. Если условие из п.1 = `false`, то выходит из цикла
4. Если = `true`, то выполняется тело цикла
5. Переход к п.1